# converting Base64 string to image using cloud functions and store in cloud storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Using front end of my application I'm storing Base64 string to cloud storage. When I store the string, it should invoke cloud function and convert the Base 64 string to image and the cloud function should save the image into cloud storage.

I was stuck getting string from storage and converting to image.

Comment: why don't you upload the file directly instead of having to encode it as base64? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: Actually i will get the image from file input and using cropper i'm  cropping it,so the file is converted as base 64 now,i need to reconvert the string into image using  cloud functions based on my requirements.

Comment: cropper can give u a blob also: `.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with React Native / Expo and found a solution here:

https://medium.com/@wcandillon/uploading-images-to-firebase-with-expo-a913c9f8e98d

> The code snippet above uploads a picture to a Firebase Cloud Function that will finally store the cloud function into Firebase Storage. Below is how the Cloud Function looks like. Many thanks to Eric Lee for showing me how to store images from a cloud function.